# how to pad zero on left with String.Format

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

i tried to use String.Format string with leading zero

```
Dim formatstring As String = ("{0,0}{1}{2,0:YYYY-MM-DD}{3}{4,0:00000}{5}{6,0:00000}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}")
```

with {4,0:00000} it would be fill zero on left 
example 
     `014`  to `00014`

with {6,0:00000} it would be fill zero on left too
example
     `547` to `00547`

but it's not happen just still shown 014 and 547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to happen, the objects passed in the 4th and 6th indices need to support the `IFormattable` interface. [From the docs:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

> If you specify *formatString,* the argument referenced by the format item must implement the [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx) interface. Types that support format strings include:
>
> - All integral and floating-point types. (See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx))
> - [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx). (See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).)
> - All enumeration types. (See [Enumeration Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e.aspx).)
> - [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) values. (See [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [Custom TimeSpan format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).)
> - GUIDs. (See the [Guid.ToString(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) method.)

That you have a value of `014`, rather than simply `14`, implies that what you have is already a string. The String type does *not* implement IFormattable. To get this to work, you need to first parse the strings to integers or similar type.